# "Upgrade" entity from base class to child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entities where one is derived from another

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        private String login;

        @Column(name = "password_hash",length = 60)
        private String password;
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bidder")
public class Bidder extends User {

@Column(length = 100, unique = true)
private String email;

}
```

When Bidder object is persisted, in both user and bidder tables created a record which have the same id value.

Initially for each system user - we create User entity, but after some time User needs to be "upgraded" to Bidder.

Is there a way I can "upgrade" User to Bidder in some elegant way?

I have several ideas -

1. insert a record in Bidder table with the same id, that User has
2. initially create Bidder entity object, but the thing is not all
       users can be Bidders
3. create BidderInfo entity class which will have
       One-to-One relatioship to User
4. don't create Bidder child class, but
       add all the needful fields from Bidder to User which will convert
       User to Bidder initially, and which is spoils the semantics of User

all the above ideas don't look like perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really want to have 2 tables you can use `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` and a `@disciminatorValue`. 
With this way, to change the type of your user you just need to change the discriminator value.

You'll find an example of "single table strategy" [to this page](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/).

This way seems to be the easiest, but it may not the best.